# python code on Raspberry Pi3 : 'float' object has no attribute '___getitem____'

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

i'm  writing e simple code that is able to read data from analog sensors, using analog to digital converter MCP3008. A first code for just one sensor works good: now i'm trying to generalize this for n different sensor using array (or list) this is a piece if my code:

```
#Define various arrays (for now only two elements)
fsr_channel=range(2)
fsr_level=range(2)
fsr_volts=range(2)
previous_fsr_level=range(2)
previous_fsr_volts=range(2)
flag=range(2)

#Initialize to zero each arrays
for i in range(2):
    fsr_channel[i]=0
    previous_fsr_level[i]=0
    previous_fsr_volts[i]=0
    flag[i]=0

#Define delay between readings
delay = 2

while True:
     for i in range(2):   
         #Read FSR value
         fsr_level[i]=ReadChannel(i)
         print(fsr_level[i])
         fsr_volts=ConvertVolts(fsr_level[i],2)

         #print out result
         print"--------------------------"

         if fsr_volts[i]!=previous_fsr_volts[i]:
            if (fsr_volts[i] > 0)&(flag[i]==0):
               print("Object is positioned on the shelf (FSR{})".format(i))
            try:
            curs.execute(""" INSERT INTO Records values(i, CURRENT_DATE(),NOW(),'Object is positioned on the shelf')""")
             db.commit()
          except:
             db.rollback()
          flag[i]=1
          print("flag{}".format(flag))
          elif (fsr_volts[i]==0)&(flag[i]==1):
               print("Object has left the shelf (FSR{})".format(i))
               try:
               curs.execute(""" INSERT INTO Records values(2, CURRENT_DATE(),NOW(),'Object has left the shelf')""")
             db.commit()
          except:
             db.rollback()
          flag[i]=0
          print("flag{}".format(flag))
    print("FSR{} volts: {}".format(i,fsr_volts[i]))
    print("previous FSR{} volts: {}".format(i,previous_fsr_volts[i]))
    previous_fsr_volts[i]=fsr_volts[i] 
#Wait before repeting loop
time.sleep(delay)
```

I obtain this error message:

```
if fsr_volts[i]!=previous_fsr_volts[i]:
TypeError: 'float' object has no attribute '___getitem____'
```

I don't know why this happens.
Anyone can give me any indication?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Somewhere in the code, you're taking a float value (let's call it `foo`) and doing `foo[i]`. With that in mind, I'm guessing that `ConvertVolts()` returns a float value or `previous_fsr_volts` is a float which can't be indexed.

Comment: Thanks Srdjani, i found my error: i forgot the index i when i called the ConvertsVolts. The correct code is fsr_volts[i]==ConvertVolts(fsr_level[i],2)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of data returns from:

```
fsr_volts=ConvertVolts(fsr_level[i],2)
```

also, for previous_fsr_volts[i]

you can get that by using *type*:

```
print(type(fsr_volts[i]), type(previous_fsr_volts[i]))
```

then convert the float type one to int:

```
int(var)
```

Probably when returning from the function

Comment: Thanks SMFSW, i found my error: i forgot the index i when i called the ConvertsVolts. The correct code is fsr_volts[i]==ConvertVolts(fsr_level[i],2)